Redirecting python script's stdin to fifo results in RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
I have this python script that's meant to function as a server which reads commands from stdin which is redirected to a fifo:
test.py:
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break

    print(f'Received: {line}')

In bash I run the commands:
mkfifo testfifo
test.py < testfifo &
echo word > testfifo

And instead of printing the line it received, the script quits with an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    line = input()
           ^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
[1]+  Exit 1                  test.py < testfifo

I've read some answers which say that there needs to be one writer to the fifo open at all times. So I tried to also run:
sleep 100 > testfifo &

Same error. I also tried replacing the input() line with this:
line = sys.stdin.readline()

And all that did was give me this error instead:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'

I'm on Windows with mingw64, I suspect this may be a bug with mingw. Any ideas? Thanks.
EDIT: Since this problem seems rather hopeless and out of my control, I've opted for now to just use a UDP server instead. Bash supports redirecting to /dev/udp/host/port which makes this easy to do.

I checked your code in a standard Linux system (CentOS 7), and it worked at the first try.

You have the issue because you are using Windows' version of Python. Can you try mingw version of Python ?

@Philippe Tried to pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python and then run the script with the installed python.exe, but still got the same error.
